# dealing with dynamically allocated array of objects of a class in another class

Tags: c++, class

I want the bag class to have an array of item objects that is dynamically allocated but not sure how to do this. Also need someone to have a look at the rest of my code. I want to add Item objects to a Bag object and perform operations on the thus formed ADT as is evident from the code.

**Item.h**

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H


class Item
{
char* item_name;
public:
    Item(char *name);
    void display_item(Item i);
    ~Item();

protected:

private:
};

#endif
```

**Item.cpp**

```
#include "Item.h"
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<malloc.h>
using namespace std;

 Item::Item(char* name)
 {
     item_name = new char[sizeof(name)];
     strcpy(item_name,name);
 }
 void Item::display_item(Item i)
{
    cout<<i.item_name<<" ";
}

 Item::~Item()
 {

 }
```

**Bag.h**

```
#include "Item.h"
#ifndef BAG_H
#define BAG_H


 class Bag
{
     int no_of_items;
     int capacity;
     Item list[];
      public:
          Bag(int no_of_items);
         void add(Item i);
         void display();
          ~Bag();

        protected:

        private:
  };

  #endif
```

**Bag.cpp**

```
#include "Bag.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include<malloc.h>
Bag::Bag(int capacity)
{
     Item list[capacity];
    no_of_items =0;
}
 void Bag::add(Item i)
{
    if(no_of_items<capacity)
    {
        list[no_of_items] = i;
        no_of_items++;
    }
   else
   {
          cout<<"bag is full";
    }


}
 void Bag:: display()
{
     for(i=0;i<no_of_items;i++)
    {
       display_item(list[i]);
    }

 }

 Bag::~Bag()
{
   //dtor
 }
```

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char*` and `std::vector<Item>` instead of `Item[]`. Also make `list` a member variable instead of a local variable of the constructor

Comment: As others said, use `std::string`, `std::vector`, and so on: don't reinvent the wheel, there were good guys writing a lot of useful stuff for you. As as side note: `sizeof(name)` does not return what you are thinking: name is a `char*`, and `sizeof(whateverPointer)` will be always the same (will be 4  for 32 bit and 8 for 64 bit architectures). If you keep using char* `item_name = new char[sizeof(name)];` shoud be `item_name = new char[strlen(name)+1];` (+ 1 for NULL terminator)

Answer (score 0):

I'll not speak on your code, if you have problems with it, ask in a separate question with minimal code to reproduce the error. Here is a link, at the end of this answer, explaining how to dynamically allocate memory for your array. If you are doing so because you need a variable sized array, I would recommend a vector. While an object of type array must have the size defined at compile time, a vector does not have this requirement, and you can use vector_pushback to add new elements with ease. But if you insist on using an array, follow the instructions here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/416/

Answer (score 0):

As possible, always use STL containers. They have analogous interface and are well documented. Most of them are dynamic. So, your code with STL containers (`std::string` and `std::vector`) could look like:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Item {
public:
    Item(const std::string& name) : item_name(name) {}
    virtual ~Item() {}

    void display_item() {
        std::cout << item_name << " ";
    }
private:
    std::string item_name;
};

class Bag {
public:
    void add(const Item& i) {
        items.push_back(i);
    }

    void display() {
        for(std::vector<Item>::iterator it = items.begin();
                it != items.end(); ++it)
            it->display_item();
    }
private:
    std::vector<Item> items;
};
```

---

As your question is aiming on how to implement your example with dynamic allocation, the code above without STL containers can be done as:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Item {
public:
    Item() : item_name(0) {} // required for new[] expression
    Item(const char* name) : item_name(0) {
        copyName(name);
    }
    virtual ~Item() {
        delete[] item_name; // don't forget to free the allocated memory
    }

    void display_item() const {
        std::cout << item_name << " ";
    }

    Item& operator=(const Item& other) { // required for copying
        copyName(other.item_name);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    void copyName(const char* str) {
        // get the size of the new name and delete the actual name
        const size_t name_size = strlen(str);
        delete[] item_name;
        // allocate memory for new name and copy it
        item_name = new char[name_size + 1]; // extra place for '\0'
        strcpy(item_name, str);
    }

    char* item_name;
};

class Bag {
public:
    Bag(size_t cap = 0) :
            items(cap ? new Item[cap] : 0), capacity(cap), size(0) {}
    virtual ~Bag() {
        delete[] items;
    }

    void add(const Item& i) {
        // "resize" the actual array if there is no space for a new item
        if(size == capacity) {
            // allocate new array and copy the actual content
            capacity += 100;
            Item* temp = new Item[capacity];
            std::copy(items, items + size, temp);
            // delete the actual array and assign the newly allocated one
            delete[] items;
            items = temp;
            temp = 0;
        }
        // add the new item
        items[size] = i;
        size++;
    }

    void display() {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            items[i].display_item();
    }

private:
    Item* items;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
};
```